# Prime Number code

Tags: java, primes

Let me start off by saying that I know there are many questions about prime numbers, this is more about my code and, specifically, the Boolean statements.

```
public class SumPrime
{


public static void main(String[] args) {


     int top = inputInt("enter the number please");   
     int sum;
     if (top > 2) {
        sum = 2;
    } else {
        sum = 0;
    }
     int i;
     int l;

     for(l=3; l<top; l+=2){

        boolean k = test(l);
        String r;
        if(k = true){
          sum=sum+l;

          output(l);
        }else {
            sum=sum;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
    }


static boolean test(int v) {

   if (v%2==0) 
      return false;
   for(int i=3; i<v; i+=2) {
       if(v%i==0)
          return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am trying to code a program that will give me the sum of primes below an input value. 
Below the above code, I have Input/Output statements, so that is not a problem.  This code seems, to me at least, that it should work without a problem.  I am relatively new to java, and very new to boolean variables and statements, so there could easily be a problem in that. (I searched for an answer, found nothing)

The test subprogram is supposed to check to see if a number is prime, and return true if it is, false if it is not.  It seems to be returning true for every value, even for numbers that are not prime. The program returns a sum of 26, rather than 17 If i input 10 as the upper limit.  It seems to be including every odd number even though it is supposed to check for primes.

I cannot figure out why this code does not work. Like I said, I think the error has something to do with the boolean method.

Comment: Use a debugger and step through your `test` method. It looks correct; if you're writing this by hand in an editor, are you sure you've recompiled?

Comment: I use BlueJ, and yes I recompiled.  It compiles fine, it just includes all odds instead of just primes.

Comment: First, corn3lius's answer seems to solve your entire problem.  But... in the future, just you a debugger and step through the suspected method line by line.  See what's actually happening one step at a time.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answers. What debugger would you recommend?

Comment: Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ, System.out.println... Just pick one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with your boolean method. Your condition is bad. You are performing an assignment in the conditional rather than actually testing equality. As a result, it always evaluates to `true`, and you end up adding where you shouldn't.

Do this instead:

```
if (k) {
  sum += l;
}
```

Incidentally, `sum = sum` doesn't so anything and should be removed too.

Comment: Thank you!!   What is wrong with the "if(k=true)" Meaning..What does that do that "if(k)" does not?

Comment: `k = true` isn't a condition. It's an assignment. In other words, you aren't testing if `k` is true. You are assigning `true` to `k`. Meanwhile, `k` already has a value from `test`. So you can just do `if (k)`. Alternatively, you could do `if (k == true)` (note the double equals), but people don't generally do that.

Answer (score 2):

if you test 9 with this i < 9 is tested. 
when i = 9 the for loop aborts and it returns true

```
static boolean test(int v) {

   if (v%2==0) 
      return false;
   for(int i=3; i<v; i+=2) {
       if(v%i==0)
          return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Edit:**

also you should never test for primes above half the target number and the ideal maximum is sqrt(x) + 1